# Is it possible to add bullet points to plot output rendered in jupyter slides?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have a jupyter slide deck consisting of seaborn plots.  I exclude the code that renders the seaborn plots.  This is the first time I've used jupyter notebook's slide options.

Is it possible to add bullet points under the actual plots to display at the same time?

Comment: As far as I know Jupyter is uses markdown for formatting. https://help.github.com/en/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax. To create a bullet you can use `'-'`.

Comment: Understand that.  I'm having to scroll from the plot to show the bullet points. I would like to show the bullet points while looking at the plot on the screen at the same time.

Comment: In the slideshow mode select `Slide` and the direct subsequent slide needs to have `-`. However this dependents on the size of the plot. If your plot uses the full height it will not show up on the same page and you will need to scroll. You can try to make it fit by modifying the HTML / CSS / JS from the slides.

Comment: Thanks all. I Leo figured out using a subsequent markdown slide as a fragment works.